# Unable to access current item in event binding in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to get the value of input element in the handler function of the keypress event binding

```
<input data-bind="textInput: searchInput, event: { keypress: filterList }" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

var ViewModel = function() {
    self.searchInput = ko.observable("");
    self.filterList = function(input) {
        console.log(input);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Instead of printing the value of input field, this prints ViewModel object.
How can I get the value of input field on each keypress in the filterList handler function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing the `input` into `self.searchInput` and it is an `observable`, you can directly use it inside the `filterList` handler -

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
    self.searchInput = ko.observable("");
    self.filterList = function() {
        console.log(self.searchInput());
        return true;
    }
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tt2ptwa/6/)

Also, I would say change the `keypress` event to `keyup` as it gives more accurate results (at least in my fiddle).

```
<input data-bind="textInput: searchInput, event: { 'keyup': filterList }" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
```

Comment: Yes, but it gives the previous value of input instead of the current, for example if there's `s` and I add `a`, it will print `s` and then if I add `w`, it will print `sa`

Comment: The `textInput` binding has all kinds of fancy event combination logic to make sure all changes to the input's value are registered. I'd advice **against** also binding to the `keyup` event. It's better to subscribe to the `searchInput` in your viewmodel. You can even throttle/rate limit your filter logic out of the box!

Comment: I would rather go for a custom binding handler for that matter. I already implemented a similar filter feature handled through it....